# The game stops when I call the microphone audio recording method and continues after a while

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this piece of code that slows down the game:

```
   audioClips[audioClips.Count - 1] = SavWav.TrimSilence(audioClips[audioClips.Count - 1], 0);
   EncodeMP3.Convert(Combine(audioClips.ToArray()), path, 44100);
```

the game continues when this code is executed.
This code is not important. It just Example. I want to understand what I can to do that resolve this problem.
How I can call these methods without slows down the game?

Comment: Both, the `EncodeMP3.Convert` and `SavWav.TrimSilence` are most probably blocking calls that take a while to finish. so you should put it on a background thread/task in order to allow the unity main thread to run smoothly meanwhile. Would help if you included the actual types you are dealing with there

Comment: I guess you are using e.g. [this script](https://gist.github.com/darktable/2317063) .. and well it is shitty ^^ you should definitely make these methods async or at least use coroutines to spread the work over multiple frames ...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]. This is [tag:c#]